# How can I ensure my not yet fetched data doesn't break my site

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently building a like button on my card component in vue. I am fetching data from firebase using middleware on a page to dispatch the `vuex` action that will go and get my user info which has their `liked_posts` stored in an array.

> The issue comes up that when I load a page requiring some of the data
>   i.e. liked_posts and my state is empty it throws a **error of
>   "`undefined`"**.

How can I make sure that even if the user hasn't signed in or hasn't ever visited that my user data wont cause an error

I have tried to change my action in the `Vuex` store to be asynchronous and use await so that I made sure the data was there, but it didn't help.
What is happening is the below code in computed properties is trying to access an object that doesn't exist in the array yet.

```
likedOrNot() {
              const likeInfo = this.$store.state.userInfoSub[0].liked_posts
              return likeInfo.includes(this.$store.state.loadedCards[0].id)
              }
```

This data isn't there yet because the user isn't signed in, exist ect. once they do and middleware is dispatching an action to fetch the user data the userInfoSub will be filled with info.

my base state looks like this when the user hasn't signed in or middleware hasnt fired to look for the user that gets put in cookies.

So I need away to ensure my lack of userInfoSub doesn't break my computer property

```
loadedCards:Array[1]
0:Object
token:null
user:null
userInfoSub:Array[0]
username:null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an opinionated answer: use [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) from [lodash](https://lodash.com/).

`npm i lodash`

Then you can write something like this:

```js
import get from 'lodash/get';

export default {
  computed: {
    isLiked() {
      const cardId = get(this.$store, 'state.loadedCards[0].id');
      const postIds = get(this.$store, 'state.userInfoSub[0].liked_posts', []);
      return postIds.includes(cardId);
    },
  },
};
```